# select connection

Tags: sql, vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdng2.png)i created two combos boxes and i retrieve the Lenses degrees for the left and right , what i tried to bring it is the cost which allocated in another table ,so please i want select statement for degrees table which have the sph , cyle , cost and i want to select the cost where sph = combobox1.text and cyl = combobox2.text

[The both two combos boxes which they have the data [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DKE6.png)

Comment: I'm normally pretty good at filling in missing info to work out what a person is asking, but I've got no idea how to interpret this question.. Can you add a lot more detail?

Comment: conn.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "select cost from degreess where sph = val(comborsph.text) and cyl = val(combolsph.text) "
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While dr.Read
            TextBox2.Text &= dr("cost") & " "


        Loop


        conn.Close()
    End Sub

Comment: thanks for your support and im sorry for the bad language , please refer to the image 1 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ElDHJedfGrBPfsyhglCUsdWj81nBFAFr/view?usp=sharing       i have two combosbox and it have two values , i want to bring the cost of those two values from another table     image 2 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ncjI20oxXu7ecOz-7cFBYBA68P3CCclI/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your SELECT statement should look like this:

```
str = "SELECT cost FROM degrees WHERE sph = " & Val(comborsph.Text) & " AND cyl = " & Val(combolsph.Text)
```

Based on the code in your comment, the rest of your code should look like this:

```
Dim str As String = "SELECT cost FROM degrees WHERE sph = " & Val(comborsph.Text) & " AND cyl = " & Val(combolsph.Text)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(str, conn)
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While reader.Read()
    TextBox2.Text &= reader("cost") & " "
End While

reader.Close()
```

This should populate `TextBox2` with the `cost` field from your degrees table.

The `conn` object was left out from your code. This code assumes it has been properly created as an [OleDbConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and opened.

Comment: thanks a lot sir for the code and really i appreciated your support , still with that im not sure how to retrieve the cost and put in textbox    ,   please see the attach file since im not aware on how to put the code here in correct shape    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjrdmbF0TYMtGapcoPWdGmGCzK8zdsMm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Val() - Is it some sort of injection hacking prevention attempt?

Comment: @CaiusJard no, it was in the original code, left it as-is.

Comment: Your crystal-ball-fu eclipses mine!

Comment: sir , really thanks a lot for your kind support .the code is working perfectly and appreciated your support